# SharedPreferences not saving for some reason

Tags: flutter

Sorry for all the commented out code. I moved some methods around but if you run it on an emulator, it doesn't save after restarting and I'm not too sure how to fix it. Instead of copying and pasting a bunch of code here, I'll send my project clone link: https://github.com/leozhang1/TODOEY.git. I used this video to help me in case you need it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPrpk_JiGvc 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

assume `saveData()` work correctly, you can move out `readData()` to `main()` 
when app restart , you can get saved data

```
TaskData td;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();    

  List<String> spList = await prefs.getStringList('list') ?? [];
  print('read spList: $spList');
  td.taskList = spList.map((task) => Task.fromMap(jsonDecode(task))).toList();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code that whenever the run the app at that time your `td = TaskData(saveData) - in readData()` && `TaskData(saveData) - This is added on your Build method` initialize.

Both objects are initialized as different instances, that's why you will get null value into your saveData() and every time you will get the null data from the SharedPreference.